# Element visibility with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, analytics-events

I'm trying to know how far my users scroll on my website. With Google Tag Manager I've set a trigger that fire an event when some marked element appears on the page. It's working but something strange is happening. On my page this is the order in vertical alignment that the elements I'm trying to track:

```
Section1
Section2
Section3
```

So, every time any users 'sees' any section on his screen I get an event. The problem is I'm getting users that sees the section 1 and 3 which is impossible because they have to watch the section2. I don't know if it's caused by the tag manager or the analytics configuration.

Comment: What happens if you press the "end" button at the top?  I'd imagine there could be ways to skip the middle.

Comment: I've tried, and I get as section 1,2 and 3 seen by the user

Comment: Could the users that are missing section 2 be on slow connections, so they never fully load the content you are using to trigger your Section 2 view event, and instead they scroll right past it without it finishing loading?